# Efficient way to detect and alert long GC pauses (young and full both)

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am currently exploring options on how to detect long GC pauses (beyond a certain threshold) and raise alerts. One simple way I can think of is writing a script/python program which periodically calls `jstat -gc ${vmid}`, reads the output, compares it with previous results and tries to raise alerts if the GC pause threshold is broken (simple if condition) . I was wondering if there are any industry standard ways to do this ? Any app/tool which can be configured with a list of running apps to be monitored ?